# Guice - Is there a way to inject a new instance of a dependent object into a Singleton?

Tags: java, guice

I have a class that has been configured to be a Singleton, like this:

```java
@Singleton
public class MySingleton {
  public MySingleton(MyDependency dependencyObj) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Is there a way to get a new instance of `MyDependency` injected into the single instance of `MySingleton` each time Guice provides it to some other class?
I can't make any changes to `MySingleton` (e.g., to make it something other than a Singleton)

Comment: If you were to inject something different in the constructor each time, then it wouldn't be a singleton anymore, because different instances would exist simultaneously

Comment: `public MySingleton(MyDependencyProvider depProvider) {}`  then when you need a new one `depProvider.get()` is the preferred method for doing this, per the Guice docs.